# Joomla 1.7 Extension Manager: Update not showing any updates

Tags: update, versions, one-click-updates

I am trying to update a Joomla installation from Joomla 1.6 to the newest Joomla version that I can, at least I am trying to get to version 2.5, and hopefully 3.X.

I have followed the instruction on [this site](http://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/upgrade-joomla-16-to-25/) to successfully update to version 1.7.0.  This is good.  The problem is: the site instructs me to use the automated updates in the Extension Manager to get the update to version 2.5.  However this is what I am seeing:

[image]

Does anyone know why it would not be showing any available updates since we all know that there should be some available?

Does anyone have a suggestion for a better way to do the update?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Eventually you need to activate the Joomla! Update Plugin.

Comment: "Joomla Update" extension is for >= 2.5.4 see https://docs.joomla.org/Joomla_Update_Missing_in_from_Admin_Menu

Comment: I think it might be relevant that the update XML file no longer includes update info for versions below 2.5 :( http://update.joomla.org/core/list.xml

I tried the admin tools extension but it tries to upgrade from 1.7 to 3.4, which is *not* successful.

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot you provided wil show updates for Extensions, not Joomla itself. So firstly, click the "Purge Cache" button, then on the top menu, go to **Components** >> **Joomla! Update**.

This should then show an update. If not, go to "Options" and ensure it it searching for Long Term Release updates.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the help.  In that link I put in the question, this is what is written to do.  However I checked it out, and I don't have the Joomla! Update option in the Components menu :-/  Perhaps what you are referring to is in a newer version?  Or maybe my update didn't work correctly.

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind - Ahh yes right you are. Hard to remember back to Joomla 1.7. So yeah, try purging the cache as shown in your screenshot and then click "Find Updates". See if this shows anything

Comment: Yes I tried that purging cache.  After purging the cache I get 1 error that seems to do with the akeeba backup component that I have installed: `Update: :Extension: Could not open http://www.akeebabackup.com/index.php?option=com_ars&view=update&task=stream&id=5&format=xml/extension.xml`.  Which also makes me think it is just checking for updates on extensions.  But anyways it doesn't come up with any updates at all.

Comment: Maybe the update packages for 1.7 no longer exist out there on the web.

Comment: Yes, they still exist. Every package for every version is kept on the server. I'm not sure why Akeeba Backup is throwing that error. Maybe try disabling Akeeba Backup temporarily in the Extensions Manager and then try to find Joomla updates

Answer (score 1):

Make a Backup first and then try this:

1. Follow this instruction to Upgrade Joomla 1.6.x to Joomla 2.5.x

http://www.ostraining.com/blog/joomla/upgrade-joomla-16-to-25/

or

[http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Upgrading_from_an_existing_version](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aUpgrading_from_an_existing_version)

1. Be sure every component, plugin, template is ready for Joomla 3.3
2. Deactivate the rememberme plugin.
3. Then go to Joomla! Update under Components Menu, then click the Options button
4. Change the Update Server Setting to Short Term Support and save
5. Then you see the newest Joomla Update and you can process the usual way.
6. Activate your rememberme plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this isn't really an answer because I've not successfully migrated from 1.7.x to 2.5 but it might be useful information for someone else, or lead to an answer.

As far as I can tell, the metadata for one-click updates for 1.x has been removed from [the Joomla update site](http://update.joomla.org/core/list.xml) so it won't find any updates available. The update site maintainers like those who have not updated their site in a timely manner to feel the salty tears of shame as they navigate through this process. As most of the existing tutorials for upgrading just point out how to do the one-click upgrade this makes things rather tricky. However, I did find [this guide](http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/joomla/upgrade/17-to-25/manual) for a manual update.

## What did work

Upgrading to latest 1.7 version (1.7.5):

1. Take a full backup of the database and files.
2. Download the 1.7.0 -> 1.7.5 Stable Patch release from [here](http://joomlacode.org/gf/project/joomla/frs/?action=FrsReleaseBrowse&frs_package_id=6259)
3. Unzip the patch update directly over your Joomla root.
4. Run database updates manually. This CLI ninja-action helped for me:

   ```
   $ ls -al administrator/components/com_admin/sql/updates/mysql/1.7.*
   ...shows list of update sql files

   ...now step through each file sequentially from the version after your original version:
   $ cat administrator/components/com_admin/sql/updates/mysql/1.7.1-2011-09-15.sql.sql  | sed s/#_/my_table_prefix/g | mysql -uroot -p my_dbname
   ```

   Obviously you'll need to substitute in your own table prefix and database name, and also input your DB password each time.
5. Check you can log into the site as an admin and check everything is working. If not, you'll need to restore your backups and start again.

## What didn't work

Having done this, I followed a similar procedure, downloading and unzipping the 2.5.28 Stable Update release, deleting the "unexisting" files as suggested in the guide (note the path they give should end `script.php` not `scripts.php`), and running through the rest of the database updates.

Unfortunately I then had a fairly non-functional site with some error messages:

```
Call to undefined method JHtml::getJSObject() in /var/www/.../libraries/cms/html/behavior.php on line 299
Call to undefined method JAdministrator::setHeader() in /var/www/.../libraries/cms/html/behavior.php on line 765
```

At this point I cut my losses and restored to 1.7.5. If anyone can get past this point feel free to add to this answer.